# Return to mailbox on delete in mutt

Tags: linux, unix, email, email-client, mutt

If you delete a message from the pager in mutt, it loads the next message into the pager.  How can I change the behavior so that it kicks me back to the mailbox when I delete a message from the pager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this macro in your muttrc:

```
macro pager d <exit><delete-message> "delete current message and exit to index"
```